# the induced maps of two continuous maps coincide (with sets of pathconnected components)

Tags: general-topology, homotopy-theory

Show that if $f_{0}: X \rightarrow Y$ and $f_{1}: X \rightarrow Y$ are two homotopic continuous maps, then the induced maps $(f_{0})_{*}: \pi_{0}(X) \rightarrow \pi_{0}(Y)$ and $(f_{1})_{*}: \pi_{0}(X) \rightarrow \pi_{0}(Y)$ coincide.

$\pi_{0}(X)$ is the set of path components of X.
(Every $x \in X$ represents an element $[x] \in \pi_{0}(X)$ and $x_{0}, x_{1} \in X$ represent the same element iff there is a path from $x_{0}$ to $x_{1}$.)

I know that $f_{0} \simeq f_{1}$. So if I can conclude that $[f_{0}(x)] = [f_{1}(x)]$ for all $x \in X$, then I know that the maps will coincide. Because then we have: $(f_{0})_{*}([x]) = [f_{0}(x)] = [f_{1}(x)] = (f_{1})_{*}([x])$ for all $x \in X$. But I think that $[f_{0}(x)] = [f_{1}(x)]$ only holds for loops, doesn't it?

Comment: What do you mean by "$[f_0(x)] = [f_1(x)]$ only holds for loops"? All you need to show is that there is a path from $f_0(x)$ to $f_1(x)$, which you should be able to construct from a homotopy between $f_0$ and $f_1$.

Comment: I read that two loops (continuous map $w: [0,1] \rightarrow X$ with $w(0) = x_{0} = w(1)$) represent the same element iff they are homotopic as loops.

Comment: Loops represent elements of $\pi_{\mathbf1}(X)$; points represent elements of $\pi_{\mathbf0}(X)$.

Comment: There is an analogous result for the induced maps between $\pi_1(X)$ and $\pi_1(Y)$, which requires showing that the loops $f_0 \circ w, f_1 \circ w$ are homotopic.

Comment: Aah, I think I was confused by that. Yeah and then they become paths if you take the composition with a path w. But I can indeed show that there is a path from $f_{0}(x)$ to $f_{1}(x)$, I think. I know that there exists a homotopy $H: X \times [0,1] \rightarrow Y$ with $H(x,0) = f_{0}(x)$ and $H(x,1) = f_{1}(x)$. And H is continuous. So can I then define w(t) = H(x,t)? That is a continuous function $w: [0,1] \rightarrow Y$ with $w(0) = H(x,0) = f_{0}(x)$ and $w(1) = H(x,1) = f_{1}(x)$.

Comment: Yes. It might be worthwhile to explain why $w$ is continuous (hint: describe $w$ as a composition of continuous functions).

Comment: Well I know that $w = H \circ pr_{2}^{-1}$. But $pr_{2}^{-1}$ is not continuous I think. And by $pr_{2}$ I mean the projection $pr_{2}: X \times [0,1] \rightarrow [0,1]$.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/124655/discussion-between-laura-van-leuven-and-themathandlanguagetutor).

Comment: Projections aren't in general invertible. However, for each $x \in X$, there is a continuous injection function $t \mapsto (x, t)$. This was introduced to me as a standard result in point-set topology when we learned about product spaces.